# Font changes size depending on looking at site with www or non-www

Tags: html, css

I have a website that seems to change size in fonts when looking at both www version and non www version.

I know the obvious answer is to setup a 301 redirect, however I am curious as to why this happens as I have never seen it before.

examples here

http://trentmcminn.com

http://www.trentmcminn.com

Comment: What browser are you using ?

Comment: Chrome on Windows Vista.

Comment: Why is this question being downvoted... it's pretty clear what he's asking, and most of us have run into this kind of problem before and been clueless what it is.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the "problem" was caused by a local difference in the OP tabs. Therefore: Too localized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not seeing any differences, but when I zoomed in on one site the font changed but the images stayed the same.  Are you zoomed in/out on one of the urls?  Try pressing Ctrl/Cmd+0 and see if that helps.

Comment: Silly me, one of the tabs was at 90% zoom....*Facepalm*  Thank you.